# Unreal Engine 3rd Person Controller Problem

Tags: unreal-engine4

Does anyone know how to make your character not rotate when using WASD keys for moving?  I want him to just run backwards and sideways, not turn around. I want only the mouse input to rotate my character.  I have the camera parented to the character's head and I'm in Third Person Template doing an FPS.

Comment: I forget what it's called exactly, but there's a bool on the character movement component. AlignRotationToVelocityDirection, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to enable `bUseControllerRotationYaw` on the Character.

Cameras and SpringArms also have a `bUsePawnControlRotation`.